# Xcode 4/Warning - Expression result unused

Tags: iphone, xcode4, warnings, expression

This is my code

```
#if defined(GIAC_NO_OPTIMIZATIONS) || ((defined(VISUALC) ||    defined(__APPLE__)) && !defined(GIAC_VECTOR))
    if (0){ 1; }
#else
```

How to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Comment out the "if"-line, it simply doesn't do anything.

Comment: I just commented the "1;" part, because there is an "else" a couple of lines below. I know that "if(0)" does not do anything but I wonder why the user wrote this piece of code... Anyway, it works fine now, thanks for the quick answer...

Comment: Yep, I'll add it as answer, so you can improve your "accept-ratio" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the warning by making the code do something. The "result" of 1 is never used. Did you mean to assign the 1 to a variable? If not, then the warning is correct. The code doesn't do anything and usually that's an indication that something's wrong with it. What were you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Then septi's comment above is correct. The line is entirely useless, so you can just comment it out. [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) is a list of gcc options if you're using gcc. Not sure of the equivalent for llvm, but you can probably find them if you search.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the "if"-line (or the "1"), it simply doesn't do anything.